# Intent's extra is always null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an `int` variable to another activity:

From the current activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

At `PlayActivity.onCreate`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
int index = Integer.parseInt(position);
```

Problem is, position is always `null` (and `parseInt()` throws exception).
Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no string extra to get since it is an `int`. You should have

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int position = intent.getIntExtra("position");
```

I'm not sure why you are trying to get a `String` then parse to an `int` when it is sent as an `int`, assuming `position` is an `int` in your first `Activity`. If that is not the case then please explain a little better.

[Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Somehow I thought you can pass only strings. Thanks!

Comment: See the link to the docs I posted. Particularly under the Public Methods and the different `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` methods. You are most welcome.