# Intent extras is null always

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for push notification and i am sending data from Notification to the activity which i am opening.

Code for building Notification:

```
private void handleNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String notTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    resultIntent.putExtra("pushNotClick", "yes");
    resultIntent.putExtra("pushNotHead", ""+notTitle);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fb_icon);
    mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(notBody)
            .setContentText(notTitle)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_not);
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And i am getting the intent extras in my activity like this:

```
String notState = getIntent().getStringExtra("pushNotClick");
String notHead = getIntent().getStringExtra("pushNotHead");
```

But the problem is, everytime the Intent Extras are null in the Activity, i have checked all the possible reasons i found here in the community, but everytime the response is same.

I have tried below mentioned links

[Intent's extra is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620698/intents-extra-is-always-null)

[Android Notification PendingIntent Extras null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596422/android-notification-pendingintent-extras-null)

[Always getting data null from notification intent android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628335/always-getting-data-null-from-notification-intent-android)

I am not sure where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I even after lots of debugging and all, couldn't find the reason of the problem. Lastly i changed the way of sending Intent extras to the activity. Now i am using bundle to send the data and its working like a charm. This is a way round and not an answer to the question, so i won't accept it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking RemoteMessage data field? 
Something like this:

```
// Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
            scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, data is coming inside RemoteMessage. Not like this but data is coming in this field.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

I had to delete from **FirebaseMessagingService** class this code:

```
override fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.handleIntent(intent)
       ...
}
```

Now, if custom data is added for Cloud Messaging I get it like this inside the app:

```
intent.extras.getString(“customer_id”)
```

This works when the app is in the background and also when the app is killed and click on Push Notification.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Are you checking in onCreate? If so, check on onNewIntent.

Comment: how does this help?

Comment: In fact, it may help, if the activity is running already, the intent should be checked in "onNewIntent". Anyway he should describe the answer in details.

Comment: Override the onNewIntent activity method. You receive a intent object here which you can get extras.

Comment: And what if the activity is not running? For example, the cloud message is passed in the notification tray while the app is closed down?

Comment: According to your code, the activity will be launched after clicking the notification and starts the activity lifecycle. That's how PendingIntent works.

Answer (score -2):

If "notTitle" is integer than send it with Intent like this

```
 resultIntent.putExtra("pushNotHead", notTitle.toString);
```

Comment: 1) That isn't valid code. 2) how is this supposed to help?

Comment: I face problem sometime when I convert to String like that ""+notTitle. Just try one time.

Comment: `I face problem sometime` what problem do you face and `""+someInt` and `someInt.toString()` will both result in the exact same thing.

Comment: Some time data send as integer but we did getString code at receiving side.